# Problem with unlocking the HTC Wildfire bootloader with HTC unlocker

Tags: htc-wildfire, fastboot, bootloader, bootloader-lock

I tried to unlock HTC bootloader by the official tool but I get to the stage when I issue the command:

```
fastboot oem get_identifier_token
```

Unfortunatly I get error

```
...
(bootloader) [ERR] Command error !!!
OKAY [  0.007s]
finished. total time: 0.007s
```

Version of firmware matches the one listed for H3G UK. The HBoot is 1.01.0002.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your HBoot needs to be upgraded, and it sounds like perhaps you didn't run the RUU to do so. The HTCdev site notes that phones with an asterisk (`*`) next to them in the list **must** run an RUU before unlocking because the bootloader on the device did not originally ship with unlocking capabilities. So *first* you need to make sure your firmware is up to date (which it sounds like it is), and then you *also* need to download and run the RUU:

> BEFORE beginning the Unlock Bootloader process your product requires
>   that you update the ROM to the version listed in the table below
>   first, then download the RUU next to it to enable the unlocking
>   capability.

The RUU's filename itself also seems to confirm this. It is listed as `PC4910000_Buzz_Froyo_hboot_1.02.0000_R3.exe`, indicating (to me, anyway) that you need HBoot v1.02.0000 in order to perform the unlock.

Comment: Would running RUU may result in any data loss?

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka: It will wipe all of your data, basically performing a factory reset.