# Problem unlocking HTC phone using their  fastboot program

Tags: fastboot, bootloader-lock

According to HTC, my Amaze 4G is fully ready from the factory to be queried for its identifier tolken, but when I run the appropriate command, it doesn't work. I get:

```
$ fastboot oem get_identifier_token
...
(bootloader) [ERR] Command error !!!
OKAY [  0.010s]
finished. total time: 0.010s
$
```

Note that someone reported the same problem, but their phone requires updating firmware and running "RUU". You can read about that [here.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19270/problem-with-unlocking-the-htc-wildfire-bootloader-with-htc-unlocker)

Same problem, different cause. Note that I did update the SDK prior to trying run fastboot - I wonder if I shouldn't have!

It's worth mentioning that I called HTC and asked for help and they were of no particular assistance; "You know more about it than I do." "How do I report a bug on fastboot?" (No useful reply to that!)

Answer (score 4):

`[ERR] Command error !!!` is a generic response from fastboot. In effect it means "invalid command arguments." Check that you are writing the command correctly, in my case I made a typographical error and this was the result.

Comment: i copy&pasted from their website and get the same error. what was your typo?

Comment: Exact same issue and you were right. I just copied and pasted from the site and it fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I got this error, solved it thanks to this thread

http://androidforums.com/desire-s-all-things-root/444571-unlock-using-htcdev-com.html

Basically, this page http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/ruu-downloads

is slightly misleading. If your device isn't listed, you might still need to update the RUU anyway.